# Compute a surface integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration, determinant, surface-integrals

I have the following problem. We are in $\mathbb R^{2n+1}$ and we want to compute $$\int_S d\mathcal H^{2n}$$
where $S:=\{(x_1,\dots,x_{2n},t): \sqrt{x_1^2+ \dots+x_{2n}^2}=r, |t|\leq r^2\}.$

We have a parametrization of $S$ given by $\phi: \mathbb S\to \mathbb R^{2n+1}, \, (x_1,\dots,x_{2n})\mapsto  (x_1,\dots,x_{2n}, x^2_1+\dots + x^2_{2n}),$ where $\mathbb S$ is the $2n-1$-dimensional sphere in $\mathbb R^{2n}$ of radius $r$.

So $$\int_S d\mathcal H^{2n}=\int_\mathbb S J_\phi dx_1\dots dx_{2n},\\
J_\phi:=\sqrt {det(\mathcal J^t\phi \cdot \mathcal J\phi) }; $$
$\mathcal J\phi$ is the jacobian matrix of $\phi$.

Now, $\mathcal J^t\phi \cdot \mathcal J\phi= I_{2n}+4A,$ where $I_{2n}$ is the identity matrix $2n\times 2n$ and $A=(a_{ij})=x_i x_j$, so $\mathcal J^t\phi \cdot \mathcal J\phi$ is symmetric. My problem is: how can I compute the determinant? Is there an easy way? Is it correct to calculate the integral in this way?

Thanks in advance, any kind of help is really appreciated.

---

**Edit:**

Ok, the parametrization is clearly wrong, so I think a correct one is simply the identity: $$\sigma: \mathbb S \times [-r^2,r^2] \to \mathbb R^{2n+1}, \quad (x,\rho)\mapsto (x,\rho). $$ In this case $J\sigma=1,$ so

$$\int_S d\mathcal H^{2n}=\int_{-r^2}^{r^2}\int_\mathbb S dx_1\dots dx_{2n} d\rho=|\mathbb S|2r^2=2n \omega_{2n} r^{2n-1} \, 2r^2=2n \omega_{2n}2 r^{2n+1}.$$

But this seems to be wrong, since on my notes I've written that $$\int_S d\mathcal H^{2n}=(2n-1) \omega_{2n}2 r^{2n+1}.$$

Comment: Your map does not seem to be a parametrization of $S $. In $S $, the last coordinate can assume negative values, but in the image of your parametrization, the last coordinate is always $\geq 0$.

Comment: This could be helpful:https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_determinant_lemma

Comment: There are faster ways to compute the (hyper-)volume of the unit ball. See library.msri.org/books/Book31/files/ball.pdf , for instance.

Comment: @PhoemueX: Oh, you're right about the parametrization!

Comment: I'm going to editing it.